# Nginx config for vue app and express server

Tags: express, nginx

I have a ubuntu server on which I have a vue app and am trying to add an express app. Everything is working correctly in my vue app but the only route that works for my express location is the index route at /api.

here is my nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html/vue/family-showdown/client/dist;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    error_page 404 /;

    location /api {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }


    location / {
            root /var/www/html/vue/family-showdown/client/dist;
    }
}
```

in my express app.js I have:

```
app.use('/', _index["default"]);
app.use('/users', _users["default"]);
```

Navigating to /api works correctly so I would expect that navigating to /api/users should work but instead I get a 404 that says Cannot GET //users

Comment: The users route works fine locally but here are the contents of my users.js file ```import express from 'express';
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

export default router;```

Comment: Take off  `proxy_redirect off;` see if that fixes it.

Comment: Also proxy_pass without the trailing  `/`.             
Just use `proxy_pass http://localhost:8080`.

Answer (score 2):

there is no any location in your nginx configuration for `/users` path. you can try this configuration.

```
location / {
    root /var/www/html/vue/family-showdown/client/dist;
    index index.html;
    include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location /api/ {
    proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

location /users/ {
    proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

and delete these configurations

```
root /var/www/html/vue/family-showdown/client/dist;

index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name _;

error_page 404 /;

location / {
    root /var/www/html/vue/family-showdown/client/dist;
}
```

Comment: for the Vue app I don't need a specific location for every URI, for example /teams successfully routes to the teams page within the app. I was hoping I could do the same for my express app, otherwise I wont be able to use things like dynamic route parameters

Comment: You keep static `/api`, you can just add to nginx `location /api/ {....`. you can make your paths like `/api/teams`, `/api/users`, `/api/${anotherpaths}`. @Adam